# C++ glm and "needs to have dll-interface" warning

Tags: c++, dll, compiler-warnings, glm-math

I have a collection of dlls using members types from glm math library, and im getting tons of warnings, so im unsure if this is okay or should i just wrap everything in my own classes?

glm is header only.

As side of the warnings everything compiles and links okay.

> warning C4251: 'Plane::m_normal' : struct 'glm::detail::tvec3' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Plane'

Comment: can you copy and paste the link errors here ?

Comment: The problem is that `glm::detail::tvec3` isn't provided by your DLL, so code using the DLL has to define their own `glm::detail::tvec3`, and it may not be structured the way your DLL expects.